# automatically increase version info on svn commit

Tags: java, svn, maven

I am using SVN to scm my maven project.
I recognized that I quite often forget to increase the version number in the pom.xml file before submitting.

Is there a way to automatically let maven, eclipse, svn or some one else do this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) can do this whenever you release your software. Doing this every commit is a bad idea, and unneeded. Alternatively, you can have your buildserver ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for example) increment the build number of the artefact produced.

And if you really, really want to increment it on commit, you can maybe use [SVN commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html).

Answer (score 2):

SVN can do this for you with [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).